# Why does the IDE break aggregates after recovery of modules?

Tags: outsystems

When starting up after a forceful termination or exception, the IDE asks to recover your work. In some cases when the recovery is complete, some of the aggregates with filters containing a LIKE condition will show up as errors in TrueChange.

Why does this happen?

Comment: This is clearly a bug on the re-assemblage of the module from its fragments in TEMP, so you should report it to OutSystems support.

Comment: Thanks @MiguelSeabraMelo. I have logged a bug with OutSystems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reported the bug to OutSystems and they have acknowledged.